# TYPO3 9.5: indexed_search unavailable

Tags: search, indexing, typo3

I want to add a search feature to a site using TYPO3 9.5.13.
No problem so far, just do a `composer require "typo3/cms-indexed-search" ^9` as indexed_search supports 9.5.

The docs then tell me to install the crawler extension (supposedly "aoepeople/crawler": "^6.7").

The catch is that the crawler docs state that it supports TYPO3 up to 8.7.99.

No-risk-no-fun so give it a try and install crawler even if it does not explicitly support TYPO3 9.5.

When selecting "info" on a page, it tells me:

`Fatal error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Controller\CommandLineController' not found in /var/www/html/public/typo3conf/ext/crawler/Classes/Command/QueueCommandLineController.php on line 38`

Looks like crawler really does not support 9.5.

This raises a few questions:

- Is it impossible to use indexed_search on TYPO3 9.5, because crawler does not support it?
- Is there a workaround? Do I really need crawler or is there another option?
- Should I opt for an alternative to indexed search, such as solr?

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crawler is only needed if you want to update the search index on a regular basis with the scheduler. If you dont install the crawler, the index is updated whenever the page is loaded from a user who is not logged in in the backend. For small up to mediate large sites this should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works for me. Sometimes the simplest things are the best.